# What is a safe way to read the PHP $_REQUEST superglobal?

Tags: php, security, superglobals

I am trying to read get parameters in such a way that will not open up potential security issues.

What I was thinking was matching the request parameter explicitly to what I expect and then setting a default for anything that doesn't match.

For example:

```
if ($_REQUEST['media'] == "video")
    $sort = "video";
elseif ($_REQUEST['media'] == "audio")
    $sort = "audio";
else
    $sort = "both";
```

Is this enough or are further steps necessary?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

What you mention is safe, but is overly verbose. Using an PHP's array operations would let PHP handle the dirty work for you:

```
$sort_valid = array('video', 'audio', 'both');
$sort = 'both'
if (isset($_REQUEST['media']) && in_array($_REQUEST['media'], $sort_valid)) {
    $sort = $_REQUEST['media'];
}
```

If this sort of superglobal parsing is common throughout your code, you could abstract this into a function that handles it for you (as many large PHP projects do).

---

As Gavin noted, it's also a good idea to use the specific superglobal that you're interested in (i.e. `$_GET`, `$_POST`, or `$_COOKIE`) if at all possible. It might not seem important now, but some ugly bugs can manefest from naming conflicts will occur between the three superglobals (e.g. `sort` in `$_COOKIE` may refer to the default sorting of search results, but `sort` in `$_GET` refers to ascending or descending order).

Comment: Throws a E_NOTICE if there wasn't a $_REQUEST['media'] set.  Should still test isset($_REQUEST['media']).

Comment: OK. Thanks for answering the question, as well as the explanation about why one should use $_GET instead of request.

Comment: Very good point Gnarf - I hadn't considered that. Edited the original post to be correct.

Answer (score 6):

It's probably also worth noting (if you're that concerned about security) that it is fairly bad practice to not know where your data is coming from. You should probably either use $_GET, $_POST or $_SESSION depending on the method of delivery.

Comment: Good catch. I figured somebody would notice that, but I wasn't sure if it mattered.

Answer (score 2):

I would add one more condition:

```
    $sort = "both";
    if (array_key_exists('media', $_REQUEST))
    {
        if ($_REQUEST['media'] == "video")
            $sort = "video";
        elseif ($_REQUEST['media'] == "audio")
            $sort = "audio";
    }
```

And yes, the $_REQUEST superglobal is the recommended way to read the request.

Comment: or `isset($_REQUEST['media'])` instead of `array_key_exists`  Also - why not just default $sort to "both" to start with?

Comment: This is the most readable way, so it is probably the method I will use.

Comment: (But using $_GET instead of $_REQUEST)

Answer (score 2):

Simplest way would be:

```
$sort='both';
$sort_valid = array('video', 'audio');
if(isset($_REQUEST['media']) && in_array($_REQUEST['media'], $sort_valid)) $sort=$_REQUEST['media'];
```

Answer (score 2):

```
$valid = array("media" => array("both", "media", "video"), ... );
$default = array("media" => "both", ...);
```

...

```
// 1. drop invalid keys
$filtered_on_keys = array_key_intersect($_REQUEST, $valid);

// 2. drop invalid values
$filtered_on_values = array();

foreach($filtered_on_keys as $key => $value) {
  if (array_search($value, $_REQUEST($key) !== FALSE) {
    $filtered_on_values[$key] = $value;
  }
}

// 3. add missing defaults
$result = array_merge($defaults, $filtered_on_values);
```

Comment: there are closing parens ) missing;    there is no function array_key_intersect() -- use array_intersect_assoc() instead;      misnamed: default != defaults --- assumes all defaults are known (no regex rules possible for instance)

Answer (score 2):

Make sure you know where the data is coming from is the best way.
// we don´t accept GET method, so, we set $media null
// if method equals post, we parse into int, so whateever comes in $_post, 
// it will not parse in string mode and we wont need to check for sql injcetion.

```
(isset($_GET['media']))? $media='': $media=(int)(isset($_POST['media'])) ? $_POST['media'] : '';

switch ($media) {
    case 1: $sort = "video"; break;
    case 2: $sort = "audio"; break;
    default: $sort = "both"; break;
}
```

by the way, you can read about $_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD']

// we use POST method in form, so...

if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD']=="GET") header('Location: http://www.disney.com/');